# Checkbox collaboration using google-drive-realtime-api

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I have created a web page which consist of text boxes and check boxes. The collaboration between the text boxes are working fine but there is no check boxes collaboration. How to do coding for the check boxes so that the collaboration can happen? An example will help greatly. Please advise...thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the state of the checkbox somewhere in the data model, probably as a boolean.  You update the value when the user checks the checkbox, and listen for change events to find out when a collaborator changed it and then update the checkbox yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to create the code as mentioned in your answer but still can't manage to figure out what code to write and in which function I should keep the code. I also tried to follow your reply at  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178447/how-to-build-and-use-a-collaborative-data-model-with-realtime-api?rq=1). This is exact code I am looking for but was not able to figure out which code goes in which functions(initializeModel, onFileLoaded, etc). Would it be possible to show which code of Alexandre Ardhuin goes in which function? Thanks in advance.